# Background service on a Glassfish server

Tags: service, glassfish, daemon

is it possible to run a background service/daemon on a glassfish server?

Best,

T

Edit:
To clarify things: I mean a daemon like a windows service, that runs in the background and gets triggered by an event.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on What do you mean by service/daemon?

Comment: Maybe the Quartz Scheduler is my solution...

Comment: Do you want it tied with e.g. a web application or installed in the stomach of Glassfish

Comment: Either way. Maybe tied to a small web application where you can start/stop the service.

Comment: Be more specific: What do you want the service to do, and what is an event?

Comment: Ok. I want the service to insert data into a database at exactly 3:00AM.

Comment: Yea, quartz coupled with a message bean should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish is Java EE container, so you can deploy any Java EE service: EJB, Webservices, JMS, etc.
If you don't want to be bound by Java EE restrictions you could develop Java application, deploy it as OSGI bundle and listen to any events available to Java Runtime.